# CakePHP and Dynamically-Related Files in Dreamweaver

Tags: cakephp, dreamweaver

It took me forever to figure out how to customize my Dreamweaver setup so that it would recognize the .ctp file extension (if you're trying to figure it out, there's a second Extensions.txt file under /Users/yourname/Library/ ...)

Now I'm trying to set up Dynamically-Related files on Dreamweaver with CakePHP, and it won't work. I'm assuming that this is because Cake is using those weird .htaccess files to prevent Dreamweaver from seeing the same directory that it is expecting.

Has anyone done this / can anyone help? All of the other q's have been left unanswered!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Not seeing"? I guess you're talking about [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Also [.htaccess files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) are nothing weird but something pretty normal in the web. Also see the [CakePHP book page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess) about mod rewrite and .htaccess. So either disable it or configure it properly.

I have no clue how dreamweaver is effected by this anyways. Does it come with a webserver?

However the best advice I can give you is simply to throw Dreamweaver away. Even after it became somewhat capable of doing non table based layouts it is still a lot faster to write the HTML/CSS manually or even faster with an editor that simply provides code/tag completion instead of this crutch Dreamweaver.

A sersious php + html/css editor is in my opinion phpstorm, if you want something free... uhm... Try Aptana or Eclipse PDT or pspad.

Comment: Firstly, this answer wasn't really an answer.
Secondly, I've used the editors you've recommended in the past, I'm giving Dreamweaver it's shot now.
I have my htaccess files and mod_rewrite properly configured on my server, but Dreamweaver's Live Code feature needs to be able to access files elsewhere in my project's directory, and I think the fact that CakePHP uses URL rewriting causes it trouble...